# Compactness and compact-finite measure in Lusin theorem (Rudin)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, compactness

I have two questions about some hypotheses in Lusin's theorem as stated in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis".
The proof initially deals with a subcase, that is the function $f$ is supposed to be limited in $[0,1[$ and the nonzero elements (through $f$) are in $A$ that is  assumed to be *compact*.

**First question**: why do we assume that $A$ is compact?

**Second question**: why do we assume the measure to be *finite* over compact sets?

I was not able to recognize where in the proof those assumptions are needed.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rudin takes an open set $V$ such that $A\subset V$ and $\overline V$ is compact. Without compactness of $A$, such $V$ would not necessarily exist.
2. Although we already assume $\mu(A)<\infty$, this isn't enough: in the course of the proof we step outside of $A$ a bit (Urysohn's lemma needs some room to work), taking an open set $V$ containing $A$. In order to keep the measure under control, we need $\mu(V)$ to be finite. The assumption that $\mu$ is finite on compact sets, together with $\overline V$ being compact, guarantee that.

By the way: the assumptions on $\mu$ to which Rudin refers to (stated in Thm. 2.14) are very common for measures found in analysis; these days one would simply say that $\mu$ is a *Radon measure*. Thus, book authors may impose this standard set of assumptions on $\mu$, even if they do not need all of them.

Comment: Why can't we just assume the existance of an open set $V$ containing $A$ such that that $\mu(V)<\infty$? Surely if every open set $V$ containing $A$, has infinite measure then $\mu(A)=\infty$