# Lusin's Theorem from Rudin's Real

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Hello I need help understanding the answer given in this question.

[Compactness and compact-finite measure in Lusin theorem (Rudin)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440516/compactness-and-compact-finite-measure-in-lusin-theorem-rudin)

I do not understand answer number 1. Could someone elaborate as to why such set $V$ would not necessarily exist (considering that the space is locally compact)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 2.7 guarantees the existence of an open neighborhood with compact closure sandwiched between every compact set and open superset, so long as one lives in locally compact Hausdorff spaces. If $A$ were not compact - for example, $A$ could be $(0,1)$ in the locally compact Hausdorff space $(0,1)$ - an open neighborhood with compact closure can't be guaranteed to exist between $A$ and $X$.