# Why was this necessary? [Lusins Theorem - Papa Rudin]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Theorem:**

> **Lusins Theorem**: Suppose $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, $\mu(A)<\infty$, $f(x)=0$ if $x\not\in A$, and $\epsilon >0$. Then there exists a $g\in C_c(X)$ such that $$\mu(\{x: f(x)\neq g(x)\})<\epsilon$$ Furthermore, we may arrange it so that $$\sup_{x\in X}|g(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$$

---

**Unstated Assumptions**

Some extra hidden assumptions are that we are working on a locally compact hausdorff space $X$, and given a measure $\mu$ with the following properties:

- $\mu(K)<\infty$ for any compact set $K$
- For any measurable set $E$ we have $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(V):E\subset V, V-open\}$
- For any measurable set $E$ with finite measure or open set $E$ then $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E, K-compact\}$
- If $E$ is a measurable set, $A\subset E$, and $\mu(E)=0$ then $A$ is measurable.

**Personal problems**
My problems has to deal with this part of the proof:

> Then $2^nt_n$ is the characteristic function of a set $T_n\subset A$, and $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}t_n(x)\quad (x\in X)$$**Fix an open set $V$ such that $A \subset V$ and $\bar{V}$ is compact.** There are 
>    compact sets $K_n$ and open sets $V_n$ such that $K_n\subset T_n\subset V_n\subset V$ and $\mu(V_n-K_n)<\epsilon/2^n$

It just seems useless to me. By this point we know that $\mu(T_n)<\infty$ because $\mu(A)<\infty$ and thus we should automatically be able to generate compact sets $K_n$ and open sets $V_n$ with $\mu(V_n-T_n),\mu(T_n-K_n)<\epsilon/2^{n+1}$ and thus $\mu(V_n-K_n)<\epsilon/2^n$. No need for $A$ to be compact, no need to generate the open set $V$ with compact closure. So why do that anyway?

Comment: maybe this answer of a similar question will help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440516/compactness-and-compact-finite-measure-in-lusin-theorem-rudin

Comment: I had the same question. Once you know that $\mu(A)<\infty$, all you need is regularity to finish. For instance,  [Cohn's proof:Theorem 7.4.4](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461469551) seems to use only regularity.